# Geometry converts from Polygon to Multipolygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, ogr2ogr, multi-polygon

I'm having difficulties with the Geometry types in PostGIS and/or ArcPy and hope some of you can shed a light on what I'm missing or how I can fix it.

I have a .gdb containing Polygons. The Table in ArcGIS lists the features as Polygons and using ArcPy using the following code I get the Output "Polygon" as well.

```
desc = arcpy.Describe("Path to Featureclass")
geometryType = desc.shapeType
print(geometryType)
```

Now when I upload the featureclass using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" “PG:host=[host] port=[port] dbname=[dbName] user=[user]" “[PathtoFileGDB]” -overwrite -skipfailures –progress
```

And then access it via psycopg2:

```
import psycopg2
from shapely import wkb

conn = psycopg2.connect(host...)
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''select * from testfeatures;''')
record = cursor.fetchall()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I'll get Multipolygons as a geometry. I already ran the "Repair Geometry" Tool in ArcGIS Pro before uploading the .gdb and the features display fine at every turn...

This sums up my problem, if you need any more information don't hesitate to ask and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: Do you get errors about non-matching geometry type if you run the command without `-skipfailures`?

Comment: no errors when omitting -skipfailures

Comment: Are there errors without `-skipfailures` but with `-nlt polygon`?

Comment: No errors, but now the output using Psycopg2 is Polygon! Thank you very much. I'll test out if my other scripts are able to process the data

Comment: That is actually not a solution but I tried to find out what happens. ESRI traditionally talks just about polygons and they can be a mixture of polygons and multipolygons. PostGIS considers that they are different and you can't insert a polygon into multipolygon table and vice versa. Ogr2ogr by default checks the type of the first geometry and my theory was that the first feature in your data was a multipolygon.